# Modul from dataframe_image._screenshot import Screenshot

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hello everyone I am a junior analyst, faced with such a problem (photo), please help. I tried updating the library and reinstalling it - it doesn't help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x646W.png)

I tried updating and reinstalling the library

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, there is no module (*.py* file) dataframe_image.screenshot in the library.

1. If you want to export (turn it into a picture) a DataFrame, consider do as the follows:

`import dataframe_image as dfi`

`dfi.export(mydf, 'mydf.png')`

where `mydf` is a `DataFrame` object, and `'mydf.png'` is the path that the picture will be saved.

2. If you want to export the whole Jupyter Notebook, there is nothing need to do in your code, just import it, and let the user use the menu `File -> Download as` to export it.

The most important thing: **dataframe_image is *not* a screenshot library, but a DataFrame exporting library**